# Angularjs show input only on the selected row

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table with edit and delete.

In my edit when the user **clicked/select** the pencil icon I want the input to show only on the selected row I used `ng-show` for this.

The problem is that its showing all the input in the table.

[image]

**html**

```
<table class="table table-sm">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Room type name</th>
        <th class="text-center">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="roomtype in vm.roomTypes1">
        <td ng-show="!vm.toogleBool" class="text-capitalize">{{ roomtype.type }}</td>
        <td ng-show="vm.toogleBool">
            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-capitalize" aria-describedby="emailHelp" ng-model="roomtype.type">
        </td>
        <td class="text-center actionIcons" ng-show="!vm.toogleBool">
            <span>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.toogleBool = !vm.toogleBool"></i>
            </span>
            <span ng-click="vm.deleteItem(roomtype._id)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
        </td>
        <td ng-show="vm.toogleBool">
            <button ng-click="vm.toogleBool = !vm.toogleBool">save</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

**boolean**

```
vm.toogleBool = false;
```

**vm.roomTypes1 data**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a694b2b5f3dfe31b045724e",
    "type": "deluxe",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:12:43.418Z"
},
{
    "_id": "5a694b3f5f3dfe31b045724f",
    "type": "superior",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:13:03.132Z"
},
{
    "_id": "5a694b435f3dfe31b0457250",
    "type": "executive",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:13:07.644Z"
},
{
    "_id": "5a694b4b5f3dfe31b0457251",
    "type": "deluxe suite",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:13:15.820Z"
}]
```

Comment: Can you please show the function that is executed when you click on the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish inline editing on a table is to pollute your data by adding a editing flag to each object on your array.

Below you can find the example of it :

```js
angular.module('app', [])
      .controller('AppController', appController);
    
    function  appController ($scope) {
      
      $scope.roomTypes = [{
        name : 'Test'
      }, {
        name : 'Test2'
      }, {
        name : 'Test3'
      }]
      
      $scope.toggleMode = function (type) {
        type.editing = !type.editing;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="type in roomTypes">
              <td>
                <span ng-if="!type.editing">
                  {{type.name}}
                </span>
                <span ng-if="type.editing">
                  <input 
                       type="text" 
                       ng-model="type.name" >
                </span>
                
              </td>
              <td>
                <button ng-click="toggleMode(type)">
                   {{type.editing ? 'Save' : 'Edit'}}
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

vm.toggleBool is bound to each edit/save button.  If you're able to add and bind to a boolean property to your vm.roomTypes1 data objects it should work.

**updated data**

```
[
{
    "_id": "5a694b2b5f3dfe31b045724e",
    "type": "deluxe",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:12:43.418Z",
    isEdit: false
},
{
    "_id": "5a694b3f5f3dfe31b045724f",
    "type": "superior",
    "__v": 0,
    "dateCreated": "2018-01-25T03:13:03.132Z",
    isEdit: false
},
...
```

**roomtype code**

```
<tr ng-repeat="roomtype in vm.roomTypes1">
    <td ng-show="!roomtype.isEdit" class="text-capitalize">{{ roomtype.type }}</td>
    <td ng-show="roomtype.isEdit">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm text-capitalize" aria-describedby="emailHelp" ng-model="roomtype.type">
    </td>
    <td class="text-center actionIcons" ng-show="!roomtype.isEdit">
        <span>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="roomtype.isEdit = !roomtype.isEdit"></i>
        </span>
        <span ng-click="vm.deleteItem(roomtype._id)">
            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </span>
    </td>
    <td ng-show="roomtype.isEdit">
        <button ng-click="roomtype.isEdit = !roomtype.isEdit">save</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```